# How to show by induction that, for $0<\theta<\pi$, $\det A_n=\frac{\sin (n+1)\theta}{\sin \theta}.$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, induction, determinant

I need help with the underlined part.
 Thanks in advance

[image]

Let $A_n$ be the $n\times n$ matrix given by
$$a_{ij}=
  \begin{cases}
    0 & \text{if }|i-j|>1, \\
    1 & \text{if }|i-j|=1, \\
    2\cos\vartheta & \text{if }i=j.
  \end{cases}
$$
If $\Delta_n=\det A$, prove that
$$\Delta_{n+2}-2\cos\vartheta\Delta_{n+1}+\Delta_n=0.$$

**Hence show by induction that,** for $0<\vartheta<\pi$,
$$\det A_n=\frac{\sin(n+1)\vartheta}{\sin\vartheta}.$$

Comment: Hello.  It is considered rude on Math.SE to post photocopies without also showing what you've tried so far on the problem.

Comment: @vadim123 But he underlined!

Comment: What's the MathJax for a thick wobbly blue underline?

Comment: I was starting with checking the formula holds for  n=1,2. Also assumed that it's true for  n=k and n=k+1...and I was trying to prove with the help of the formula sin(a-b)=sinacosb-sinbcosa

Comment: @proofy Do you know what $A_n$ looks like? After you know this I'm confident it's easy to find the determinant of $A_{n+1}$ in terms of $A_n$ by developing the determinant along the last collumn (for instance).

Comment: @proofy I've try to add the text copied from the picture. If you insist on underlining instead of boldface, you can use `$\underline{\text{Hence show by induction that}}$`, but it does not look nice (in my opinion): $\underline{\text{Hence show by induction that}}$.

Comment: @Martin Sleziak Thank you very much!

Comment: BTW [this question](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292449/how-to-workout-the-determinant-of-the-matrix-d-n-alpha-beta-gamma) gives a generalization of the recurrent relation from your question.

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to check this for $n=1$ and $n=2$.

In the inductive step you simply have to apply 
$$\frac{\sin\alpha+\sin\beta}2=\sin\frac{\alpha+\beta}2\cos\frac{\alpha-\beta}2$$
to $\alpha=(n+3)\vartheta$ and $\beta=(n+1)\vartheta$.

(This is one of the [sum-to-product](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Product-to-sum_and_sum-to-product_identities) identities.)

---

Adding more details:

The inductive step (if we assume the validity of the formula for $n$ and $n+1$ and we want to verify whether it is true for $n+2$) is equivalent to verifying whether
$\Delta_{n+2}-2\cos\vartheta\Delta_{n+1}+\Delta_n\overset?=0$ 
holds for $\Delta_n=\frac{\sin(n+1)\vartheta}{\sin\vartheta}$.

This is equivalent to
$\Delta_{n+2}+\Delta_n\overset?=2\cos\vartheta\Delta_{n+1}$
$\frac{\sin(n+3)\vartheta}{\sin\vartheta}+\frac{\sin(n+1)\vartheta}{\sin\vartheta}\overset?=\cos\vartheta\cdot\frac{\sin(n+2)\vartheta}{\sin\vartheta}$
$\sin(n+3)\vartheta+\sin(n+1)\vartheta\overset?=\cos\vartheta\sin(n+2)\vartheta$

This is precisely the above equality with $\alpha=(n+3)\vartheta$ and $\beta=(n+1)\vartheta$.

Comment: If I may ask, when I inputting the trig equation $\det A_n=\frac{\sin(n+1)\vartheta}{\sin\vartheta}.$ . into the equation above it $\Delta_{n+2}-2\cos\vartheta\Delta_{n+1}+\Delta_n=0.$ , where the inductive step came in? Is it simply by viewing that the equation  $\Delta_{n+2}-2\cos\vartheta\Delta_{n+1}+\Delta_n=0.$ came in at first place by induction (I mean by using cofactors and minors)?

Comment: @proofy I've added some details about inductive step. I thought that you already know how to derive the recurrent equation $\Delta_{n+2}-2\cos\vartheta\Delta_{n+1}+\Delta_n=0$  and you are asking how to get the final formula for $A_n$ from this equation. Did I misunderstood what you are asking?

Comment: @ Martin Sleziak I grateful to you for your explanation!!! Sorry for coming up with another question,but is the induction hypothesis was done for n=k and n=k+1?

Comment: @proofy The way I wrote it in my post, in the inductive step we are trying to prove the formula for $n+2$, assuming that both $\Delta_{n+1}$ and $\Delta_n$ have that form.

Comment: @ Martin Sleziak Thank you very much again! I really appreciated your professional help!