# Recursive relation for a characteristic polynomial

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

I need to find a recursive relation for the characteristic polynomial of the $k \times k $ matrix $$\begin{pmatrix} 0 & 1 \\ 1 & 0 & 1 \\ \mbox{ } &  1 & . & . \\ \mbox{ } &\mbox{ } & . & . &. & \mbox{ } \\ \mbox{ } &\mbox{ } &\mbox{ } & . & . & 1 \\ \mbox{ } & \mbox{ } & \mbox{ } & \mbox{ } & 1 & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

I calculate the $3 \times 3$ and $4 \times 4$ case but I couldn't deduce a recursive formula.

Answer (score -1):

The characteristic polynomial of your matrix (say, $A$) is the determinant of the *tridiagonal Toeplitz matrix* $xI-A$. So, as long as you know how to evaluate the determinant of a tridiagonal matrix recursively (see [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/292449/how-to-workout-the-determinant-of-the-matrix-d-n-alpha-beta-gamma) and its answers for examples), you can deduce a recursive formula.